# Where and based upon what template are rails route helpers defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview, actionpack

Rails URL helper methods like **user_path** are defined dynamically, but **where exactly?**

To which module/class/classpath do they belong?

Answer (score 1):

They're defined here...
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0814bb62e5128aff7bfa55211efbd10ad3e37c07/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb

As near as I can see it's...

`ActionDispatch::Routing::NamedRouteCollection`